# What is the green arrow on the 777's airspeed tape? Does it exist on other types as well?

Tags: feature-identification, airspeed, boeing-777, glass-cockpit

[image]
Image source: [fsnews.eu](https://fsnews.eu/flightfactor-previews-pfd-and-nd-for-777-v2/)

I found this green arrow on the primary flight display (PFD) of a 777. What does it show? I'm assuming it's for showing acceleration and deceleration but I am not too sure. Is my assumption correct? Also, does it exist on other aircraft types?

Comment: Anyone else perplexed by the 30 knots *and* the bank? :D

Comment: @ymb1 According to the link you found, it's from a sim product, which is still in development. I guess they are just showing off what the PFD *could* display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The green arrow is the **speed trend vector** showing predicted airspeed in 10 seconds:

> [image: 777 Airspeed Tape]
>
> **2 Speed Trend Vector**
>
> Indicates predicted airspeed in ten seconds based on current acceleration or deceleration.

<sup>(Boeing 777 FCOMv2 10.10.4 - Flight Instruments, Displays - Controls and Indicators)</sup>

Other Boeing aircraft with a speed tape on the PFD (or ADI for early 757/767) have the same feature (I checked 737NG, 747-400, 747-8, 767 and 777 FCOMs). All have very similar descriptions, although the one for the 747-8 is more detailed:

> **Trend Indication**
>
> The tip of the arrow indicates predicted airspeed in ten seconds based on airspeed,
> inertial data, and winds. Rapidly changing wind speed or direction can affect
> predicted airspeed with no change to indicated airspeed.

Airbus aircraft also have a very similar feature, as already explained in this question: [What scale is the speed trend line on a PFD's ASI?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49933/what-scale-is-the-speed-trend-line-on-a-pfds-asi)

Comment: The Garmin G3X has an airspeed trend line too.